# Preencher um select com o value de outro usando .NET Core MVc

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc-5, razor-pages

Alguém sabe como preencher um select a partir do value de outro, sendo que os dois são preenchidos através de dados vindos do banco, utilizando a linguagem C# .NET Core MVC com páginas Razor.

Comment: Yan, benvindo ao StackOverflow em Português. Coloque um exemplo de código para que seja possível te ajudar. A pergunta está ampla e a resposta não será objetiva.

Comment: Se entendi bem, você você está falando de dropdown list, certo?
Sua pergunta dar a entender que você já consegue preencher um deles, mas quer preencher um outro a partir do evento de seleção do anterior.
Se for isso mesmo, pesquise por "cascading dropdown list".

Answer (score -3):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#primeiroSelect').change(function(){ 
        var primeiroValor = $(this).val(); 
        $.ajax({ type: 'POST', url: '/Controller/Action', 
            data: { primeiroValor: primeiroValor }, 
            success: function(result){
                $('#segundoSelect').html(result); 
            }
        }); 
    });
});
```